# What exactly is this patent on?

Tags: patent-infringement

In reference to the patent: [US20140149315](https://www.google.com/patents/US20140149315)

is this patent an international one?
Also what exactly is this patent protecting? this website does the samething twitter or facebook does.

Comment: That is an application not a patent. The issued patent is https://www.google.com/patents/US9135662. Take a look at it’s claims and see it is clearer to you.

Answer (score 1):

The issued US patent for the cited application is [US9135662B2](https://patents.google.com/patent/US9135662B2/en). This is a US patent and only covers the United States. It is possible there are international equivalents filed, but it isn't indicated by patents.google.com. To understand what is covered by a patent, it is necessary to read and parse the claims. Here is the first claim.

> 1. A method for communicating information, the method comprising:
>
>    providing and/or receiving with a data processor a continuous feed of
>      relevant data extracted from a machine-readable data broadcast of
>      financial news analytic data and/or a trading exchange data;
>
>    the data processor automatically ranking the relevant data; the data processor
>      automatically creating graphical output data messages from the
>      extracted relevant data, wherein the graphical output data messages
>      differ in content and/or format from the continuous feed of relevant
>      data and the data broadcast;
>
>    the data processor automatically
>      delivering the graphical output data messages to a user device;
>
>    the data processor automatically determining highly ranked distinct
>      financial events from the extracted relevant data;
>
>    the data processor
>      automatically creating spoken audio output data messages for the
>      highly ranked distinct financial events;
>
>    and the data processor
>      automatically delivering the spoken audio output data messages to the
>      user device.

As you an see, there is a lot to this, but it seems to be a method for aggragating financial data and providing a graphical output along with spoken audio. There several other independent claims (13, 15 and 19) also. To infringe on this patent you must implement each and every step of at least one claim.

As for whether this just duplicates Facebook or Twitter, I won't comment as I'm not an expert (especially with Twitter). I will say, this fits a form of software patent I find problematic as it’s claims pretty much state **what it does**, but not **how it does it**. In my opinion, the how is what should be patentable not the what. This patent was issued after the [Alice Decision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alice_Corp._v._CLS_Bank_International) so one would hope the USPTO kept that in mind.